# Can I alias a member of the base class in derived class without increasing class memory?

Tags: c++

I would like to do something like this:

```
template <int N, typename type>
class BaseClass{
public:
    type array[N];
};

template <typename type>
class Derived : public BaseClass <1, type>{
public:
    type &alias = ( BaseClass<1, type>::array[0] );
};
```

but when I use:

```
cout << sizeof( Derived <char> ) << endl;
```

it prints out 16, I would expect it to print 1 or 5, not 16. Is there a way to do it so it takes only `sizeof(array[N])`? Why 16? When I change `BaseClass<1, type>` to `BaseClass<3, type>` it also prints out 16.

EDIT:

I found a way around this for my needs:

the base class:

```
template <typename container, int N>
class BaseClass : public container {
public:
    // constructor example
    BaseClass(){
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            container::array[i] = 0;
    }

    // function examples
    BaseClass operator+( const BaseClass& arg ){
        BaseClass result;
        for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
            result.array[i] = container::array[i] + arg.array[i];

        return result;
    }

    friend ostream& operator << ( ostream& stream, const BaseClass& arg ){
        for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
            stream << arg.array[i] << ' ';
        return stream;
    }
};
```

for a derived class I would use something like this:

```
template <typename type>
class container3{
public:
    union{
        type array[3];
        struct{
            type x;
            type y;
            type z;
        } ;
    };
};

class Derived : public BaseClass< container3<float>, 3 >{
public:
    Derived( float x = 0, float y = 0, float z = 0 ){
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
    }
};
```

now I can use them like this:

```
Derived var1( 1, 2 );
Derived var2;

var2.y = 3;
var2.z = 6;

cout << var2 + var1 << endl;
cout << sizeof( Derived ) << endl;      /// this prints 12

return 0;
```

Comment: What is `sizeof(void*)` on your platform?

Comment: `cout << sizeof(void*) << endl;` outputs 8

Comment: Aha, so you're on a 64-bit platform (data pointers and references will take 8 bytes each).

Comment: ok, now I get why 16, but no way to create an alias with no memory overhead? Isn't it basically a rename of the same variable?

Comment: No. An reference is an actual variable in its own right. It's essentially semantic sugar for a pointer (with a few added constraints on how it can be used, notably that it can't be null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it print 16?

First of all, this is implementation defined. But here is a plausible explanation.

The reference in the derived class costs you the size of a pointer, which, on a 64 bit platform, is likely 8 bytes. The array of 1 `char` in the base class costs you an additional byte. However, due to alignment restrictions, the compiler rounds 1 + 8 up to 16, as your platform probably likes addresses to be aligned to 8 bytes.

> What can I do about it?

Get rid of the reference. If it's always going to point to the array in the base class, there is no need to store it as a member. If you think that spelling out the `BaseClass<1, type>::array[0]` every time is too much typing, you can add a member function.

```
type&
getit() noexcept
{
  return BaseClass<1, type>::array[0];
}
```

This will not increase your object size.  You'll probably also want a `const` overload.

Answer (score 0):

Not without increasing the size of the object, no.

But you can write a method that does the same thing, and call that method everywhere you'd use the reference. It will be inlined when compiled with optimizations on and shouldn't result in much overhead compared to the alias (or any overhead at all, if the common subexpression elimination pass is good enough, which it will be in your example since the aliased expression is as simple as can be).

```
template <typename type>
class Derived : public BaseClass <1, type>{
public:
    type& alias() { return array[0]; }
    type const& alias() const { return array[0]; }
};
```

The reason your object size was 16 is because the compiler creates structures that are padded to a multiple of your machine word size. This allows you to create arrays of such structures without worrying about weird alignment (and without having gaps in between instances).

I suspect your machine word size is 8 bytes (64-bit CPU). So, 8 bytes for the reference `alias` (which is really just a special syntax around a pointer), plus one for the `array`, plus 7 bytes of padding to bring it to a multiple of 8.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ standard it is *unspecified* whether a reference takes up storage.  So you will only be able to investigate this case by trying it out and seeing what happens.

Having a reference member of your class means that the default-generated copy-constructor, move-constructor, and assignment operators won't work properly though. So this adds considerable complexity to your class.

Of course you could write:

```
type &alias() { return BaseClass<1, type>::array[0]; }
```

which won't take up storage.